# How to set nginx reverse proxy at localhost

Tags: angularjs, nginx, cross-domain, reverse-proxy

I attempt to do reverse proxy to resolve the cross-domain issue, and I have done my nginx.config file like below:

```
    server {
       listen 8080;
       root <here is my project url>;
       index index.html;
       server_name localhost;

       location ^~ /api/ {
           rewrite ^/api/(.x) /$1 break;
           proxy_pass http://www.example.com:80/;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_buffering off;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

and actually the localhost was setup successful.
But I still cannot get the token inside response headers from server api and also cannot add customer headers inside request headers, I try to call http  get request to local data.json and the customer was added...

sorry for every one, I want to present my situation and I'm not good at english, hope every one can get me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You might have to set headers with Authorizaiton which has the token.
proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;